# Item position not updating in onBind method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am implementing interface to detect when view is clicked in recycler view. I am removing the item when button is clicked. It works fine when once button is clicked. But when I click second time it removes the view present next to it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            optionsClickEvent.onDeleteClicked(position, imagePath);
            showToast(String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });

}
```

Above code is executing in onBind. Next I am removing:

```
@Override
public void onDeleteClicked(int position, ArrayList<String> filePath) {
    filePath.remove(position);
    imageAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

This works one time perfect. But items are not updated. And when I click delete button second time the item is removed at position+1.

Comment: position is layout position or adapter position? try using adapter position

Comment: I don't know. See the code above. I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User holder.getAdapterPosition() instead of layout position in onClick

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        optionsClickEvent.onDeleteClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition(), imagePath);
        showToast(String.valueOf(position));
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why holder.getAdapterPosition() gives -1 when used in method showToast()?